# Jquery plugin Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'observe' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Hi made attempts to install the Jquery plugin chosen which enables me to customise my `<select>` tag in all browsers. [Click here](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) Anyway i have integrated this pluigin into my site and i have come across the following error message in my element inspector..[Click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/Express)

"TypeError: Object # has no method 'observe'"

from the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.observe('dom:loaded', function(evt) {
var select, selects, _i, _len, _results;
if (Prototype.Browser.IE && (Prototype.BrowserFeatures['Version'] === 6 || Prototype.BrowserFeatures['Version'] === 7)) {
  return;
}
selects = $$(".chzn-select");
_results = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = selects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  select = selects[_i];
  _results.push(new Chosen(select));
}
deselects = $$(".chzn-select-deselect");
for (_i = 0, _len = deselects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  select = deselects[_i];
  _results.push(new Chosen(select,{allow_single_deselect:true}));
}
return _results;
 });
 </script>
```

Does anyone know how i can solve this problem??

Comment: post your html. Exact from `DOCTYPE` to closing `</html>`

Comment: hahahaha I don't think that's wise have over 5k lines of html

Comment: Why do you mix prototype and jQuery? That's pretty nasty...

Answer (score 2):

That error means only one thing: you either do not have `Prototype` in your html-document or it is loaded after your script (from your code example) is executed. Post complete `html`-code somewhere (to JSFIDDLE for instance) to get more precise answer.

You have that code:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
</head>
```

Before it place another `script` tag with the inclusion of the Prototype:

```
<script src="/path/to/Prototype.js"></script>
```

And place `Prototype.js` file to `/path/to/` folder on your server.

Then since you use `Jquery` on your project call `jQuery.noConflict()` (after `jQuery` inclusion) so that `$` symbol of the `Jquery` will no conflict with the `Prototype`'s one.

```
     <script>
         var $jq = jQuery.noConflict()
     </script>
</head>
```

And replace all the jQuery's `$` with the  `$jq` in ALL your js on the page (where it is related to the Jquery, not Prototype)

Comment: @NewBoy, try to add `console.log(Prototype)` before `document.observe('dom:loaded'` to see whether it is present

Comment: it says prototype is not defined

Comment: @NewBoy, so this is your problem. Try to  check where it is included (it has to be before your code), then check whether it is loaded (may be you have an error in your URI or it is not present on the server)

Comment: @NewBoy, in the `php` you've posted there is no `Prototype` inclusion at all. You can try to include it by yourself. Add `<script src="/path/to/Prototype"></script>` to the `<head>`.

Comment: @NewBoy, and do not forget to call `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: can you post an example of this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16740/discussion-between-newboy-and-caligula)

Answer (score 0):

What's document.observe?  Try window.onload= function{} instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload= function(evt) {
var select, selects, _i, _len, _results;
if (Prototype.Browser.IE && (Prototype.BrowserFeatures['Version'] === 6 || Prototype.BrowserFeatures['Version'] === 7)) {
  return;
}
selects = $$(".chzn-select");
_results = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = selects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  select = selects[_i];
  _results.push(new Chosen(select));
}
deselects = $$(".chzn-select-deselect");
for (_i = 0, _len = deselects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  select = deselects[_i];
  _results.push(new Chosen(select,{allow_single_deselect:true}));
}
return _results;
 };
 </script>
```